# Electric shower is cold in the morning

Tags: electrical, plumbing

I have a new 8.5kW mains fed electric shower (Triton T80z) which is cold in the morning but warm in the evening.

It has a low pressure indicator light on it so I know it's not a pressure problem (unless the light is broken...).

Anyone have any ideas on how to remediate this?

EDIT:
Thanks DDS, some great info and options there. In the morning it doesn't heat the water at all so it comes out at mains temperature. I've fiddled with the settings (both elements on, max temp set etc) but with no difference made.. any ideas on why it'd do that?

Comment: What temperature is mains in the morning and evening? Can you be sure both elements are working? maybe one is faulty? Maybe the switch is faulty? (I'd return the unit for a replacement - faulty or not fit for purpose)

Comment: Does reducing flow help?  Are you quite sure cold water isn't colder in the morning?

Comment: I have a small electric water heater for washing horses, if it quits working it is usually the thermal safety in the unit itself. I have to pull the cover and push a manual reset to get it working again.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How cold? (20°C, 30°C)
Remember that in winter mains water is colder (5°C vs summer's 15°C) and at night it gets even colder: 2° On average, and with a 8,5 kW you can rise only 3,5L/min at 35°C delta (which is really low flow).  It means a 37°C shower in morning and 40°C in evening.

I think its a too low power appliance: consider switching to instant-gas that allows by-far better performances. Even going for a 10 or 12 kw electric shower won't improve much your situation. Remember: a flow of 1L/Min (starting at 5°C) requires a power of 2,4 kW. And a good shower (at least in my Italian terms) is 10L/min, although 6L/min is still acceptable.

Another electric option is to install a Point-Of-Use immersion that can give you really better performances (for 2-people shower 40L is enough), at least in winter.

Comment: Thanks DDS, I've added some more info to the original question

Comment: Only 1 thing: check if the shower's electric circuit has a timer or an economy7 reciver. If so disable (by-pass) it.

Comment: I expect those winter mains-water temperatures are different in Saskatoon than in Darwin. An 8.5kW electric shower is adequate where I live.

Comment: Had a look through the spec but it doesn't seem so, it's a Triton T80z. :(

Comment: Not a timer 'inside' your shower, but a timer on the power line feeding your shower, the first place I'll check would be next to the breaker box.